# i want shortcut of my app button on other already lauched app . Like messenger or hike application. (That button should be adjustable too)

Tags: android

I want to show my app button on the already launched apps. For Example if i open any app which is installed in my phone. My app button should be visible in that app. That button should be adjustable too. For example we have facebook messenger, its last open chat button always visible to us on screen.

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want a floating widget into view hierarchy of current screen. So, this floating view is always on top of application window.

Implementation:

1st step:
add a permission in your manifest file
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
This permission allows an app to create windows , shown on top of all other apps.

Next
you have to create a background service ( e.g FloatingBackGroundService.java) to add your app icon layout at the top of window.

Next
To enable the app icon Drag along figure, override onTouchListener() . whenever user touch the app icon , you will record the initial X and Y coordinates and when user move finger, app will calculate the new X and Y coordinates.

Also, implement click listener to close the app icon by stopping the service when the user clicks on the close icon at the top-right of the app icon (cross icon).

So finally your FloatingBackGroundService.java will look like below:

```
public class FloatingBackGroundService extends Service {



private WindowManager mWindowManager;
   private View mChatHeadView;




 public FloatingBackGroundService() {



 }




@Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }




@Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       //Inflate the chat head layout we created
       mChatHeadView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_chat_head, null);


       //Add the view to the window.
       final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
               PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

       //Specify the chat head position
//Initially view will be added to top-left corner
       params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
       params.x = 0;          
       params.y = 100;

       //Add the view to the window
       mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
       mWindowManager.addView(mChatHeadView, params);


//….
//….
   }


   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       if (mChatHeadView != null) mWindowManager.removeView(mChatHeadView);
   }
} 
    }
```

Your MainActivity from where you will request DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION and start a background service to display app icon at the top of all applications.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION = 2084;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Check if the application has draw over other apps permission or not?
        //This permission is by default available for API<23. But for API > 23
        //you have to ask for the permission in runtime.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {

            //If the draw over permission is not available open the settings screen
            //to grant the permission.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            initializeView();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set and initialize the view elements.
     */
    private void initializeView() {
        findViewById(R.id.notify_me).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingBackGroundService.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {

            //Check if the permission is granted or not.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                initializeView();
            } else { //Permission is not available
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Draw over other app permission not available. Closing the application",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                finish();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Your XML layout to display app icon (layout_chat_head)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/chat_head_root"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Profile image for the chat head.-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chat_head_profile_iv"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_circle"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <!--Close button-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_btn"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is it useful only for chatting app or i can use it for any button of my app?

Comment: I have a button in my layout which take my app to the main menu activity. I want that button to show on other apps.

Comment: yes you can display any where.  definitely you have to implement that logic in  above background service